# Georeference raster file (TIFF) with known CRS and with world file available

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, georeferencing, world-file

I have the following components:

1. Unreferenced raster file (TIFF) (e.g. myraster.tiff) with desired coordinate reference system (CRS) added to the properties of the raster file within QGIS
2. World file (e.g. myraster.wld) as plain text containing georeferencing information for the raster file
3. QGIS-project (e.g. myproject.qgz) prepared with desired CRS

Adding the raster file to the QGIS-project does place the raster file as a non-georeferenced layer, i.e. the georeferencing information in the world file is neglected. Is it feasible to get the raster file georeferenced with the information provided?

I am using QGIS-Version 3.10.0 in Windows 10.

Comment: If the world file is correct, then you should **not** set the "desired CRS" in raster properties. Just load it and let the world file place it properly. If you want to reproject the original to some other CRS, then do that from the Raster menu -> Projections -> Warp.

Comment: @Micha - it still needs to know the projection, add a `myraster.prj` file containing the required projection from http://epsg.io

Comment: Rename your world file TFW and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make use of the `.wld` file (and that name is fine or you could rename it to `.tfw`) QGIS must know what the numbers in the world file mean. That means it must know what the projection of the data is to make it line up with your other data. To do this you need to tell it what the projection is. There are two ways to do this, one go to http://epsg.io and look up the projection you need then save the string it provides as a `.prj` file (with the same basename as the rest of the files) QGIS will then read this file and use it to set the projection. Or, if you plan to save the raster as a GeoTiff and never use it again you can use the `set crs -> set layer crs` option in the layer menu of QGIS. **This is pretty much the only time you should ever use this option, i.e. when you actually know better than QGIS.**

Comment: It worked fine with the "Well Known Text as HTML".