# Georeferencing PNG image in QGIS when the coordinates of image corners are known

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, georeferencing

I have the image such as this:

[image]

everything would be fine, but I cannot really use the normal georeference method explained here:

https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/georeferencing_basics.html

because I can't see the boundaries at all.
I tried to set up the georeference points manually, although even there I have to put them in the map and alternatively provide the coordinates manually.
My situation is somewhat upside down, because I can't see the image borders, but I know roughly the coordinates of its corners and the middle point. The problem is, that I don't know how to find it with the [Georeferencer](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_georeferencer.html) plugin.

I found some hints, which say, that the process is possible with GDAL:

[How to geo-reference a tif image knowing corner coordinates](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/380607/how-to-geo-reference-a-tif-image-knowing-corner-coordinates)

[Georeference image using center point and size?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340981/georeference-image-using-center-point-and-size)

but the problem is, that I don't know how to run the GDAL console and where to put these values in.

The links beneath:

https://gdal.org/programs/gdalinfo.html

[How to edit the GDAL/OGR console call in QGIS 3.0?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273192/how-to-edit-the-gdal-ogr-console-call-in-qgis-3-0)

weren't helpful enough for me.

I am asking then about the possibility to georeference the PNG raster image in the situation, where borders aren't visible (the image includes transparent white background, so any styling couldn't work) but the coordinates of the corners and the middle point are known. Alternatively, is there an opportunity to see the image bounds in the GDAL georeferencer plugin?

**UPDATE:**

After typing in the OSGEO console

```
     gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_srs 'EPSG:<4326>' -a_ullr <-3> <52> <-2> <51> <C:\Users\k\Desktop\elrrachidia - fez\Viewshed\Heywhatsthat\BHX\cloakpN52W003.png> <C:\Users\k\Desktop\elrrachidia - fez\Viewshed\Heywhatsthat\BHX\cloakpN52W003.tif>
```

I am getting an error:

**< was unexpected at this time**

How I did wrong here?

Comment: You could create the pgw file, if you know the coordinate of the corner and the resolution!

Comment: Where can I create this type of file?

Comment: Just create it in a text app, and change the extension! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file

Comment: yes, but how to include the .png image within it? In the text app I can only provide the coordinates and that's it

Comment: At the end, you have your image.png and image.pgw! The pgw contains only 6 lines with size in x, rotation y, rotation x, size y, x-coord (center pixel upperleft) and y-coord (center pixel upperleft). Then, just load your raster and it should go at the correct place!

Comment: I found something here:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88813/how-can-i-correct-a-pgw-file-for-a-png-image
but it seems, that the GDAL is required. Is it the value I can put straight to the notepad and save it as the .pgw file then?

Comment: I had my comment as a answer cause it's a bit long...

Comment: I still don't understand this process :(

Comment: A georeferenced PNG has 2 files. The .png (the image itself) and a second file .pgw. The PGW has the same name as your PNG file, and contains only the information to project the corresponding PNG at the right place. So in your case, you just need to create this file in WORD for exemple, and change the extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, just say that you work in meter, and the resolution of your png is 25 cm, and your png has no rotation. So your pgw file looks like that:

0.25

0.00

0.00

-0.25

2539000.049999999813735

1153999.949999999953434

Save it as name_of_your_png.rtf and change the extension to pgw. So it means:

- Line 1: resolution in x (25 cm)
- Line 2: no rotation in y
- Line 3: no rotation in x
- Line 4: resolution in y (25 cm)
- Line 5: coordinate in x for the center of the upper left pixel (change it for fitting your case)
- Line 6: coordinate in y for the center of the upper left pixel (change it for fitting your case)

When you load your PNG, no need to have GDAL.

Comment: OK, It seems to work, although is there some way to put the coordinates the same as WGS 84?
Your example coordinates 1153999.94999999953434 correspond to Latitude 10.3250N and 2539000.04999999813735 to Longitude 22.84924E.  How to make it suitable i.e. with WGS84?  I have an error: CRS not defined - defaulting to WGS84. Is there any way to set the CRS in the PGW file?

Comment: from what I understand world files never have CRS stored in them, you need to define the CRS manually when loading it into a GIS, see this answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/349278/98784 (note it also suggests the option of using a .prj file but this hasn't worked for me).

Comment: Correct. Don’t need to set a CRS. Once the PNG loaded, you can give it the correct CRS.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `gdal_translate` (https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html) with parameter `-a_ullr` to georeference your image. In the example below I'm georeferencing a PDF file:

```
gdal_translate --config GDAL_PDF_BANDS 4 --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 1024 -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co ZLEVEL=9 -co PREDICTOR=2 -co TILED=YES -a_srs EPSG:31255 -a_ullr 9623.23 326346.38 9933.23 326090.63 file.pdf file.tif
```

Comment: yes I think I know it. The problem is, that I have no knowledge of where to put these expressions in.

Comment: You have to enter the command in the OSGeo4W Shell.

Comment: I am getting an error:  < was unexpected at this time. See my question update

Comment: If you remove all < and > it should work.

Comment: Now I have: ERROR 6: Unknown option name '-'

Comment: OK, the code could work, but as a result, I got an error:

ERROR 1: PredictorSetup:Horizontal differencing "Predictor" not supported with 2-bit samples